# TFS 2012 default PBI (Story) in defined iterations

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Currently using TFS 2012, we have multiple scrum teams sharing the same backlog and the same iterations. I'm trying to find a way to have a default PBI (Story) appear in each Iteration (Sprint) across all the teams. Is this possible or does each team need to define the PBI themselves in each iteration.

Comment: PBIs can only be in one iteration and on area path.  If all of the teams are using the same backlog and iterations then any PBIs defined on the backlog and in a given iteration should be visible to all teams.

Comment: What do you want to do with this default PBI? What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible. Best method would be to have each team create their own PBI and associate that PBI with the original one.